# How can I Skip the first Two Strings from each line?

Tags: java, arrays

Can someone please help me skip the first two strings from each line. The "add cities" and the next string after it.

add_cities Riyadh Ar-Riyad Al-Kharj Ad-Dawadmi

add_cities Makkah Makkah-al-Mukarramah Jeddah Taif

add_cities Qassim Buraidah Unaizah

I am trying to get the words after them and output them into another file. It should look like this:
[Command] add_cities
-> City: Riyadh

- Ar-Riyad  + Al-Kharj  + Ad-Dawadmi

[Command] add_cities
-> City: Makkah

- Makkah-al-Mukarramah  + Jeddah    + Taif

[Command] add_cities
-> City: Qassim

- Buraidah  + Unaizah

  ```
   for (int i = 0; i < city.length; i++) {

        out.println("[Command] add_cities");
        out.println("-> City: " + regions[i]);
        for (int j = 0; j < city[i].length; j++) {

            city[i][j] = sc.next();
            out.print("+ " + city[i][j]);
        }

        out.println();
    }
    out.flush();
    out.close();
  ```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Seems your [example] is incomplete: missing declaration of `regions` and you did not specify __which _other_ file__ than `out` to print the string-remainder. Please add and clarify!

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to String.split() function. It can be used to split the string based provided pattern and returns an array of strings.
I have provided a sample code to help you out.
Since you wish to ignore  first two strings, you should start from index 2 of the array.

```
public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "add_cities Riyadh Ar-Riyad Al-Kharj Ad-Dawadmi";
        String str2[] = str.split(" ");
        System.out.println(str2[2]+"+"+str2[3]+"+"+str2[4]);
    }

}
```